# Uploading Video on Facebook using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a single video on facebook using the latest `https://graph-video.facebook.com` graph api. Following is my code:

```
public void ExternalShare()
{
try
{
    var fbp = new FacebookClient("user_access_token");

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "multipart/form-data", FileName = "SampleVideo2" }.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Video\SampleVideo2.mp4"));
    parameters.title = "Small New Video";
    parameters.description = "Having Fun";
    string url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com" + "facebook_User_Id" + "/videos";
    dynamic result = fbp.Post(url, parameters); 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

}

After execution. this code giving no exception but every time i execute i am receiving the same id as a response:

[image]

**Question 2**: If there is no exception then this video is not showing on my timeline

Comment: Most likely, because they detect the data is the same, so they just return the existing. Try altering data every time such as `FileName`.

Comment: @Bauss i already did this but again the same thing is happening

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

> When including a source parameter, you should include a filename with
>   the correct extension that indicates the type of file container

Just add **.mp4** to the **FileName**

```
FileName = "SampleVideo2.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its Old Question but I found the error in it.so Hopefully it Helps Others.

```
 string url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com" + "facebook_User_Id" + "/videos";
```

this Line Missing '/' after facebook.com so it should be like this

```
 string url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" + "facebook_User_Id" + "/videos";
```

and Problem Solved.